# Derivative changes sign for continuous and differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Give $f$ is continuous and differentiable, if $f'(a) < 0 < f'(b)$, can we say there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ ?

My gut feeling is yes, using Rolle's theorem. If $f(a) = f(b)$, apply Rolle's theorem directly. Else wolg. suppose 
$$f'(a) < 0 < f'(b), \text{ if } f(a) < f(b)$$ 
define another continuous differentiable function
$$g(x) = f(x) - f(a),$$
then $g(a+\epsilon) < 0$ and $g(b) = f(b) - f(a) > 0$, by intermediate value theorem there exists $b' \in (a,b)$ such that $g(b') = f(b') - f(a) = 0$. Applying Rolle's theorem on the sub interval $(a,b')$, we will get the wanted result.

If $f(a) > f(b)$, define $h(x) = f(x) - f(b)$. We have $h(b) = 0, h(b-\epsilon) <0$ and $h(a) >0$. Then using intermediate value theorem and Rolle's theorem like above will get our wanted result.

Comment: This looks fine. Your statement is a particular case of [Darboux's Theorem](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDarboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)&ei=DznWU_ayOOfC8AGlh4DAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFxejgueM5dArhquGyG-cdQp_8SWg&bvm=bv.71778758,d.b2U).

Comment: This a special case of Dini's intermediate value theorem: if $ f $ is differentaible on $ (a, b) $ and $ f'(a)\le \lambda \le f'(b) $ then there is $ c\in (a, b) $ s.t. $ f'(c)=\lambda$

Comment: @DavidMitra It seems to me that OP used the continuity of the derivative to justify the existence of $ϵ$ such that $g(a+ϵ)<0$

Comment: @G.T.R I used the definition of derivative $$\frac{g(a+\epsilon) - g(a) }{\epsilon} < 0.$$ And thank you guys for the replies!

Comment: @G.T.R If $h(a+\epsilon)\ge h(a)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then ${h(a+\epsilon)-h(a)\over \epsilon}\ge0$ for all $\epsilon>0$. It then follows that $h'(a)$ can't be negative.

Comment: You should (in my opinion) also give the proof for the case $f(b)<f(a)$, since then it is seen the hypothesis that $f'(b)>0$ is needed.

Comment: @DavidMitra I added that part. You are right, I only wrote down the argument, and technically my proof was not complete without $f(b) < f(a)$.